# Updating UI in windows 8 C#

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding, windows-8

I have a page called AllPageView which has a GridView. The datatemplate for the GridView is as follows

```xml
<GridView.ItemTemplate>
     <DataTemplate>
          <Canvas Width="{Binding TemplateWidth}" Height="{Binding TemplateHeight}">
              <Canvas.Background>
                  <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding PageBackground}"/>
               </Canvas.Background>
                <Image Height="{Binding TemplateHeight}" Width="{Binding TemplateWidth}" Source="{Binding Page}" Stretch="Uniform" Opacity="1" CacheMode="BitmapCache" />

                   <StackPanel x:Name="EditDeleteStackPanel" Width="{Binding TemplateWidth}" Height="{Binding TemplateHeight}" Opacity="0.95">
                       <Button x:Name="NoteDelete"  HorizontalAlignment="Right"   VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="{x:Null}" Tapped="NoteDelete_Tapped" MinWidth="50" MinHeight="50" Margin="0,0,10,0" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" >
                           <Button.Background>
                               <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding Delete}"/>
                           </Button.Background>
                       </Button>
                       <Button x:Name="NoteEdit"  HorizontalAlignment="Right"   VerticalAlignment="Top"   FontFamily="Segoe Script" FontSize="24" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Tapped="NoteEdit_Tapped" Foreground="{x:Null}" MinWidth="50" MinHeight="50" Margin="0,0,10,0">
                           <Button.Background>
                               <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding Edit}"/>
                           </Button.Background>
                       </Button>
                  </StackPanel>
           </Canvas>
       </DataTemplate>
</GridView.ItemTemplate>
```

The Image has its height and width bound to `TemplateHeight` and `TemplateWidth` of the `Page_Collection` class respectively. I have a better and setter for `TemplateHeight` and `TemplateWidth`.

```
public static int TemplateWidth
{
    get { return m_templateWidth; }
    set 
    { 
        m_templateWidth = value;                
    }
}
```

The problem is, I have now a need to resize the image sizes from a page called `General`. 
When a toggle switch is toggled, I need to change the size of the image. Like this

```
private void OnCompactCategoryToggled(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (compactCateg.IsOn == true)
    {
        Page_Collection.TemplateHeight = 100;
        Page_Collection.TemplateWidth = 350;
    }
    else
    {
        Page_Collection.TemplateHeight = 200;
        Page_Collection.TemplateWidth = 700;
    }
}
```

Though the `AllPageView` page is bound to `Page_Collection`, the values does not get updated and hence the image size is the same. `Genera`l is a `Flyout` in the `SettingsPane`.

I'm very new to Windows 8 and this is my first time `DataBinding`. Could someone please tell me where I'm going wrong or if I'm missing something?

**EDIT**

This is the code behind for `AllPageView`. I call `Load_PageCollection` in the constructor of the class

```
public async void Load_PageCollection()
{
    m_pageConfig = new PageConfig();
    Page_Collection[] tmppage = await m_pageConfig.Read_FromJSONFile(App.PAGECONFIG);
    List<Page_Collection> tmp;
    if (tmppage != null)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < tmppage.Length; i++)
        {
            tmppage[i].UpdateCompletionStatus();
        }
        tmp = tmppage.ToList();
        ObservableCollection<Page_Collection> NoteCol = new ObservableCollection<Page_Collection>(tmp.ToList<Page_Collection>());
        PageCollection = NoteCol;
        PageLV.DataContext = PageCollection;
        m_pageManager.InitilizeWithFileLoc(PageCollection.ToArray());
    }
    else
    {
        PageCollection = new ObservableCollection<Page_Collection>();
        PageLV.DataContext = PageCollection;// PageLV is the grid view. The gridview, the image and a stackpanel.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited after updated code.

You will need to move your template properties into a separate class that supports INotifyPropertyChanged and then refer to this class from each of your PageCollection instances....

```
public class PageCollectionTemplate : INotifyPropertyChanged {

   private static readonly void m_Instance=new PageCollectionTemplate();

   private int m_templateWidth;

   public static PageCollectionTemplate Instance {
     get { return m_Instance; }
   }

   public  int TemplateWidth {
        get { return m_templateWidth; }

        set 
        { 
            if (m_templateWidth == value) return;
            m_templateWidth = value;                
            OnPropertyChanged("TemplateWidth");
        }
    }
    // Do same for template height...

   protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName) {
     var handler=PropertyChanged;
     if (handler!=null) handler(this,new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
  }

  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

}
```

UPDATE, I missed out this bit before,iIn your page collection class

```
public PageCollectionTemplate Tempate { 
    get { return PageCollectionTemplate.Instance; }
}
```

Then update your bindings to be `{Binding Template.TemplateWidth}`.

There are alternative implementations you could by setting the source of the binding to the singleton instance eg:

```
{Binding TemplateWidth,Source={x:Static w:PageCollectionTemplate.Instance}
```

But you will need to define the namespace for `w`

**Do not be tempted to implement the following because the notify property changed events will not fire!**

```
public int TemplateWidth {
   get { return PageCollectionTemplate.Instance.TemplateWidth; }
   set { PageCollectionTemplate.Instance.TemplateWidth=value; }
}
```

Comment: I have implemented the INotifyPropertyChanged and have created
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string name)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
            }
        }

The GridView has a collection of images, so if i create an instance of PageCollection, do i have to update each image individually?

Comment: I tried, No matter what it jus would not update. I initialised an instance of Page_Collection, removed the static of TemplateWidth. :(Is this something to do with the mode of binding? OneWay TwoWay?

Comment: Im having trouble in creating the property getter. Im getting an error "Member names cannot be the same as their enclosing type". Is is because I already have a constructor named Page_Collection??? :(

Comment: While creating the instance of Page_Collection, I did like this Page_Collection pc = Page_Collection.Instance; It would suffice right? It is still not updating, I found tht the PropertyChanged in the OnPropertyChanged is null no matter what. :(

Comment: Can we clarify, you talk about multiple images in the gridview so you are binding the view to a collection.  In this DataTemplate WHAT is the class of each item?

Comment: @alfah answer has now been modified to match your question

Comment: One quick question, this is class a part of the same Page_Collection class? else properties like m_templateWidth cannot be accessed right?

Comment: @alfah No it is seperate, I forgot to include the field. Now corrected.  PageCollection shouldn't reference the templatewidths at all just this class

Comment: @alfah updated again, I'd missed out the property you put into PageCollection

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18954/discussion-between-alfah-and-bob-vale)

Answer (score 0):

The class containing the definition for TemplateWidth needs to implement INotifyPropertyChanged, and the setter for TemplateWidth needs to raise the PropertyChanged event.

```
public int TemplateWidth
{
    get { return m_templateWidth; }

    set 
    { 
        m_templateWidth = value;    
        if (PropertyChanged!=null)
        {
             PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("TemplateWidth"));
        }            
    }
}
```

Using frameworks like Prism or SimpleMVVM can simplify the coding for this type of thing 
and also relieve you from relying on constants like "TemplateWidth".

Comment: my bad, didnt notice the static keyword.

Comment: @Gavin Sinai I tried, No matter what it jus would not update. I initialised an instance of Page_Collection, removed the static of TemplateWidth. :(Is this something to do with the mode of binding? OneWay TwoWay?